# Keep focus on row after datagridview update

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, focus

I'm creating an VB windows application. The point of the application is a simple `DataGridView` where I'm fetching a `View` from a SQL Server database.

The `DataGridView` is refreshed every second so I could see new data income in my GridView.

The problem is keeping focus on row after the refresh. I need the solution, where after I click a row, or a cell it keeps me on it even after the refresh.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Refresh every 1 sec
        Dim timer As New Timer()
        timer.Interval = 1000
        AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf timer_Tick
        timer.Start()
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'XYZDataSet.view1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.View1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.XYZDataSet.view1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("DayTillDelivery").Value <= 30 Then
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("DayTillDelivery").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'Calling refresh after 1 second and updating the data
        Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Me.View1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.XYZDataSet.view1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved a similar problem in the past by storing the indexes of the selected cell in a variable before doing the refresh, so I'm able to restore the selection by calling `DataGridView.Rows(selRow).Cells(selCol).Selected = True` after the update.

---

### Edit - Sample Code:

> **To later readers:
> Please take a look at Edit#2 where I describe a better method to re-select the previous selected cell!**

Sample Code:

```
'   Variables for remembering the indexes of the selected cell
Dim selRow As Integer
Dim selCol As Integer

'   Check if there is a selected cell to prevent NullPointerException
If DataGridView1.SelectedCells().Count > 0 Then
    selRow = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    selCol = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
End If

'   Dummy "update"
'   don't forget to clear any existing rows before adding the new bunch (only if you always reloading all rows)!
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
For index = 1 To 20
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
Next

'   Check if there are "enough" rows after the update, 
'   to prevent setting the selection to an rowindex greater than the Rows.Count - 1 which would 
'   cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException
If (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) > selRow Then
    '   Clear selection and then reselect the cell that was selected before by index
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    '   For the next line of code, there is a better solution in Edit #2!
    DataGridView1.Rows(selRow).Cells(selCol).Selected = True       
End If
```

**Please note:**

- This procedure requires you to add the rows in the exact same order that you have added them before the update, as only the `.Index` of the selected row is stored in the variable. If you readding the rows in a different order, then not the same row but **the row at the same position** will be selected after the refresh.
- You should add check if there is a selected row at all (to prevent a `NullPointerException`) and if there are "enough" rows in the `DataGridView` **after** the refresh, to prevent an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- This only works if the `DataGridView1.SelectionMode` is to something that actually selects rows, like `FullRowSelect`.
- Don't forget to clear any existing rows before adding new ones by updating (only if you always reloading all rows).

---

### Edit 2 - RowHeader triangle and accidental MultiSelect

As stated in the comments below, there was an odd behavior that would lead to an accidental MultiSelect, if the user holds down the mouse button past the refresh cycle. Also, the RowHeader triangle was not set to the correct row.

After some research I found a solution to this behavior. Instead of setting the `.Selected`-property of a given cell to `True`, set the `.CurrentCell`-property of the `DataGridView` to the cell you would like to select!

In code, this means changing

<s>`DataGridView1.Rows(selRow).Cells(selCol).Selected = True`</s>

to

**`DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(selRow).Cells(selCol)`**

and there you go. :-)

Comment: Could you see where would I implement that in my code?

Comment: In the same method (Sub) you're doing your update in. Your actual update-code replace the tiny loop marked with `Dummy "update"` in my example.

Comment: That means: `timer_Tick`.

Comment: Yes I have added it before and after refresh,the parts of code.
But now I have another problem. I didn't mention that I would like to keep the cell focused too. And not only that, when I press the whole row it focuses me on it, and after refresh the arrow jumps back to first data.
You can see the focus [here](http://imgur.com/UduEuqp)
And after refresh [here](http://imgur.com/wmNz8Ym)

Comment: Evil answer: set `DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False` and the arrow-issue will be gone. ;-) Honest answer: I don't know how to fix this at the moment, as I always switched off the row headers when I was working with the DGV because imho they are just a waste of space.

Comment: To keep the cell selected: Like the `.SelectedRows()`-property, the `DataGriedView`-control has also a *`.SelectedCells()`*-property, that you can use to modify the given code to keep the focus on a selected cell. Select a cell, throw in a BreakPoint in your `timer_Tick`-sub and the take a look at the `DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex` oder `.ColumnIndex`-propertys.

Comment: This is the answer to my question, but still I got more questions...As seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/x30D0Gi.png) When i click the selected column and hold to the interval of the refresh it selects(goes) to the first row...How can I escape this behavior?

Comment: Interesting. After some research, I found a solution to this behavior, please see **Edit #2** of my answer. This is why I like stackoverflow so much, you're always learning new stuff on the fly when you're trying to find a solution to a given problem. :-)

Comment: Could you update your answer with Row and Cell..so it would be final, since the answer is great! Right now it's only with Row

Comment: Thank you. :-) I just edited the answer to better match the final solution.

Comment: Still problems in the code...It doesn't save the column,and if clicked after second update it returns to first row.

Comment: Hm, the code is working fine in my isolated testing project... Have you tried setting a BreakPoint at the top of `timer_Tick` to evaluate the value of `selCol` and if it gets set at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83539/discussion-between-fin-and-m463).

Comment: Your answer is awesome. Edit 2 works for me. I get row selected and in focus between bunch of data rows

Answer (score 2):

Before Fill, store the CurrentRow values and currenCell column:

```
Dim currentColumnIndex As Integer = 0 ;
Dim currentValues As List(Of Object) = If(DataGridView1.CurrentRow Is Nothing, Nothing, New List(Of Object)())
If currentValues IsNot Nothing Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        currentValues.Add(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(i).Value)
    Next
currentColumnIndex = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
End If
```

After Fill, search the row corresponding to stored values:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count AndAlso currentValues IsNot Nothing
    Dim areIdentical As Boolean = True
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    While j < DataGridView1.Columns.Count AndAlso areIdentical
        areIdentical = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = currentValues(j)
        j += 1
    End While
    If areIdentical Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(currentColumnIndex)
        currentValues = Nothing
    End If
    i += 1
End While
```

*Note: the "For/While" loop coding is perhaps not optimal because it results from automatic conversion from C# to vb.net.*

Comment: This is also a good approach, as checking for the actual cell values will prevent you from selecting the wrong cell if the rows are loaded in a different order (or the row that was selected before is no longer part of the DGV), but comes at a serious performance coast, especially if you're dealing with several thousands of rows, which is a likely scenario in any little more sophisticated business application. Also, how would you make sure to select only the right cell if there are redundancies in the cell values?

Comment: The performance cost for restoring the current row is a minor issue compared to the Fill() cost. If rows are duplicated, there is no mean to choose between rows matching the previous row : if feasible, choice depends on application context.

Answer (score 0):

C# fix code , next reload  pattern

```
if (dataGridView7.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(selcell + "------"+dataGridView7.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.ToString());
    if (selcell > 0 && dataGridView7.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex==0) {  }else
    {
        selrow = dataGridView7.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        selcell = dataGridView7.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    }

}

loaddataJobsall();
dataGridView7.ClearSelection();
dataGridView7.Rows[selrow].Cells[selcell].Selected = true;
```

Comment: dataGridView7.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = selrow;

dataGridView7.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = selcell;



# If you want to use the scroll update